# How to hide keyboard on enter key

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext

i have an activity with four edittext and i want to hide keyboard when users finish to use one of the four edittext. if i click enter on keyboard, it will focus another edittext and keyboard still remain, but i need to hide keyboard, so to use only one edittext and not necessarily the other.
This is xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="@drawable/sfondo">
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/backPersonalizza"
        android:src="@drawable/back" android:background="@null"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"></ImageButton>
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" android:id="@+id/testoSuggerimenti"
        android:text="Personalizza il testo e le icone. Clicca su una delle icone e scegli l'immagine preferita"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        ></TextView>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_marginTop="20dp">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <EditText android:layout_height="40dp" android:id="@+id/editT1"
            android:layout_width="115dp" android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp" android:gravity="center"
            android:ellipsize="end" android:singleLine="true">
            <requestFocus></requestFocus>
        </EditText>
        <EditText android:layout_height="40dp" android:id="@+id/editT2"
            android:layout_width="115dp" android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:gravity="center" android:ellipsize="end"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:singleLine="true"></EditText>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="wrap_content">
        <ImageButton android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/tasto1"
            android:id="@+id/tastoMod1" android:background="@null"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp" android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"></ImageButton>
        <ImageButton android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/tasto2"
            android:id="@+id/tastoMod2" android:background="@null"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp" android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"></ImageButton>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout6"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <EditText android:layout_height="40dp" android:id="@+id/editT3"
            android:layout_width="115dp" android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp" android:gravity="center"
            android:ellipsize="end" android:singleLine="true"></EditText>
        <EditText android:layout_height="40dp" android:id="@+id/editT4"
            android:layout_width="115dp" android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:gravity="center" android:ellipsize="end" android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"></EditText>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout7"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <ImageButton android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/tasto3"
            android:id="@+id/tastoMod3" android:background="@null"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp" android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"></ImageButton>
        <ImageButton android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/tasto4"
            android:id="@+id/tastoMod4" android:background="@null"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp" android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"></ImageButton>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

can you help me?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I am not sure but you should try this code:-

```
youredittext.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
            // hide virtual keyboard
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(youredittext.getWindowToken(), 0);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

I hope this will help..

Comment: i will try! but in this way it will override only enter key, not other true?

Comment: I edited my answer and I think to try you attach the OnEditorActionListener to all of them.

Comment: Strange effect for me, hit enter but keyCode is 0. Solved using event.getKeyCode()

Answer (score 19):

The Best Way To Do This, Is To Add Following Codes In XML File

```
android:imeOptions="actionDone"
```

Comment: perhaps it's because the edit text is generated programmatically and there is no xml file to edit....

Comment: Nope! read ques first... he said he have 4 editText and he wants to hide keyboard when someone finish typing on any of editText

Comment: because if you set, for example, the TextView.OnEditorActionListener on your EditText, keyboard will not hide on enter button hit. If there was a better option, worse option would be deprecated:)