# Hidding keyboard after enter key is pressed

Tags: android, keyboard

Simply question - how to close virtual keyboard after hitting enter key/button?

I've tried this [Handle “Enter” key on Jelly Bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21834494/handle-enter-key-on-jelly-bean) and [How to hide keyboard on enter key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864671/how-to-hide-keyboard-on-enter-key), but none of this works for me.

Comment: The code in the second link should work, I was going to provide the same answer. what happened when you tried it?

Comment: Nothing for some reason, enter key worked like it usually do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options.

With xml:

```
 <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"/>
```

and with code.

```
edittext.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if (event != null&& (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                    InputMethodManager in = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    in.hideSoftInputFromWindow(edittext.getApplicationWindowToken(),InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: XML code worked, but Java code had no effect. Still wondering why not.